# django error is displayed deliverately short?

Tags: django, exception

For example I get

```
ApiFieldError: ApiField...value.",)
```

When actual error is

```
raise ApiFieldError("The model '%r' has an empty attribute '%s' and doesn't allow a null value." % (previous_obj, attr))
```

Is this a normal behavior? How do I fix it?

I'm on emacs pdb, if that matters.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with emacs pdb.

Comment: Thanks reporting. Will check this for python-mode.el also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1256216